# How to pivot a pandas table just for some columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have a datafame in pandas with has a group of columns with hyphens (theres several but I'll use 2 as an example, _1 and _2), which both depict a different year.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['BP','Virgin'],
                   'B(LY)': ['A','C'],
                   'B(LY_1)': ['B', 'D'],
                   'C': [1, 3],
                   'C_1': [2,4],
                   'D': ['W','Y'],
                   'D_1': ['X','Z']})
```

I'm trying to reorganise the table to pivot it, so that it look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['BP','BP', 'Virgin', 'Virgin'],
                   'Year': ['A','B','C','D'],
                   'C': [1,2,3,4],
                   'D': ['W','X','Y','Z']})
```

But I can't work out how to do it. The problem is, I only need the the hyphen column to match the equivalent hyphen for the other variables. Any help is appreciated, thanks

**EDIT**

here is a real life example of the data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['BP','Virgin'],
                   'Account_date(LY)': ['May','Apr'],
                   'Account_date(LY_1)': ['Apr', 'Mar'],
                   'Account_date(LY_2)': ['Mar', 'Feb'],
                   'Account_date(LY_3)': ['Feb', 'Jan'],
                   'Acc_day': [1, 5],
                   'Acc_day_1': [2,6],
                   'Acc_day_2': [3,7],
                   'Acc_day_2': [4,8],
                   'D': ['W','A'],
                   'D_1': ['X','B'],
                   'D_1': ['Y','C'],
                   'D_1': ['Z','D']})
```

desired output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['BP','BP','BP','BP', 'Virgin', 'Virgin','Virgin', 'Virgin'],
                   'Year': ['May','Apr','Mar','Feb','Apr','Mar','Feb','May'],
                   'Acc_day': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                   'D': ['W','X','Y','Z','A','B','C','D']})
```

Comment: can you supply a desired result based on you desired data? do you have any constraints about the data?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
# set A aside
df2 = df.set_index('A')
# split columns to MultiIndex on "_"
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

# reshape
out = df2.stack().droplevel(1).rename(columns={'B': 'Year'}).reset_index()
```

Or using janitor's [`pivot_longer`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```
import janitor

out = (df.pivot_longer(index='A', names_sep='_', names_to=('.value', '_drop'), sort_by_appearance=True)
         .rename(columns={'B': 'Year'}).drop(columns='_drop')
      )
```

Output:

```
        A Year  C  D
0      BP    A  1  W
1      BP    B  2  X
2  Virgin    C  3  Y
3  Virgin    D  4  Z
```

##### updated example

using a mapper to match `(LY)` -> `_1`, etc.

```
import re

# you can generate this mapper programmatically if needed
mapper = {'(LY)': '_1', '(LY-1)': '_2'}

# set A aside
df2 = df.set_index('A')
# split columns to MultiIndex on "_"
pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, mapper))
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace(pattern, lambda m: mapper[m.group()], regex=True).str.split('_', expand=True)

# reshape
out = df2.stack().droplevel(1).rename(columns={'B': 'Year'}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        A Year  C  D
0      BP    A  1  W
1      BP    B  2  X
2  Virgin    C  3  Y
3  Virgin    D  4  Z
```

Comment: Thanks mozway, this is very much appreciated. Also thanks for the quick response.
I'm sorry, but my original code wasn't quite right, my apologies. I've amended it to include a more accurate version. Sorry again, but any help you can provide would be amazing, thanks

Comment: so how do you match `LY` and `_1`? are your `LY` and `LY-1` literals? (if not, please rather be explicit with the real data)

Comment: Its a time series, so LY, C, D etc are the current value, and LY_1,C_1,D_1 etc are a 1 year time lag, _2 is 2 years etc. Sorry, there were more problems with the code that would make it hard to understand, my apologies. Hopefully its clear now. And thanks again

Comment: see the updated example, if this is still not working with your data, please provide a real-life example

Comment: I've just updated with real life example. I think your code with mapper should work fine, but unfortunately I'm using a work terminal, and its a very old version of pandas I can't update (also very limited on available packages unfortunately). Its version 0.23, so series.droplevel() isn't supported and I don't know how to work around it